# How can I retrieve UTM source from google analytics? - React

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

Google analytics is setup I'm trying to grab the source so that I may pass it to my backend server and store it.

Is this possible? If so how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'Core Reporting API' of Google Analytics:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries

Using a query with this parameters you can returns information like source and medium, i.e.:

```
dimensions=ga:source,ga:medium
metrics=ga:sessions
```